# Use multiple CKEDITOR in Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor, textarea

I am new to Rails, i am trying to use multiple CKEDITOR for my rails project when i am using it multiple times its showing error.

```
Uncaught The editor instance "options_attributes_0_text" is already attached to the provided element.
```

Here this is what i am doing.

```
= f.input :text, label: false, :as => :ckeditor, :input_html => { :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'mini'} }
= f.input :text, label: false, :as => :ckeditor, :input_html => { :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'mini'} }
= f.input :text, label: false, :as => :ckeditor, :input_html => { :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'mini'} }
= f.input :text, label: false, :as => :ckeditor, :input_html => { :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'mini'} }
```

I am getting only one CKEDITOR, rest three are simple text areas which showing the same error as mentioned above.

My config.js file:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{

  /* Filebrowser routes */
  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed.
  config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Flash dialog.
  config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Flash dialog.
  config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Link tab of Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads.
  config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";


  config.autoGrow_onStartup = true;

  config.toolbarCanCollapse = true;
  config.toolbarStartupExpanded = false;

  // Rails CSRF token
  config.filebrowserParams = function(){
    var csrf_token, csrf_param, meta,
        metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'),
        params = new Object();

    for ( var i = 0 ; i < metas.length ; i++ ){
      meta = metas[i];

      switch(meta.name) {
        case "csrf-token":
          csrf_token = meta.content;
          break;
        case "csrf-param":
          csrf_param = meta.content;
          break;
        default:
          continue;
      }
    }

    if (csrf_param !== undefined && csrf_token !== undefined) {
      params[csrf_param] = csrf_token;
    }

    return params;
  };

  config.addQueryString = function( url, params ){
    var queryString = [];

    if ( !params ) {
      return url;
    } else {
      for ( var i in params )
        queryString.push( i + "=" + encodeURIComponent( params[ i ] ) );
    }

    return url + ( ( url.indexOf( "?" ) != -1 ) ? "&" : "?" ) + queryString.join( "&" );
  };

  config.toolbar_mini =
    [
      // { name: 'document', items : [ 'NewPage','Preview' ] },
      { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
      { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','Scayt' ] },
      { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak' ] },
              '/',
      { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format' ] },
      { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Strike','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
      { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote' ] },
      { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
      { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize','-','About' ] }
    ];

  config.toolbar = 'mini';


  // Integrate Rails CSRF token into file upload dialogs (link, image, attachment and flash)
  CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ){
    // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    var content, upload;

    if (CKEDITOR.tools.indexOf(['link', 'image', 'attachment', 'flash'], dialogName) > -1) {
      content = (dialogDefinition.getContents('Upload') || dialogDefinition.getContents('upload'));
      upload = (content == null ? null : content.get('upload'));

      if (upload && upload.filebrowser && upload.filebrowser['params'] === undefined) {
        upload.filebrowser['params'] = config.filebrowserParams();
        upload.action = config.addQueryString(upload.action, upload.filebrowser['params']);
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Please post your `config.js` code.

Comment: @Pavan I have updated my the code above please have a look and help me out thanks